# How to deserialize DateTimeOffset during aggregation

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, datetimeoffset

I have the following code.

```
class TheThing
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<TheThing>("theThings");

    var theThing = new TheThing()
    {
        Number = 1,
        Date = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    };

    collection.InsertOne(theThing);

    var theFirstItem = collection.Aggregate()
        .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "Number" }, { "firstDate", new BsonDocument { { "$first", "$Date" } } } })
        .First();

    var firstDate = theFirstItem["firstDate"].ToUniversalTime();
}
```

The document saved in the database is the following.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62ba1b93fd0318e0c3db5935"),
    "Number" : 1,
    "Date" : [ 
        NumberLong(637919607231619015), 
        0
    ]
}
```

The document resulting from the aggregation pipeline is something like:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "firstDate" : [ 
        NumberLong(637919607231619015), 
        0
    ]
}
```

Anyway, the last line throws an exception:

`System.NotSupportedException: 'BsonArray does not support ToUniversalTime.'`

How is it possible to get the DateTimeOffset back after an aggregation?

Comment: It seems you are trying to call `ToUniversalTime` on the actual `BsonArray`. Check the structure of `theFirstItem` to see if you can find the actual `BsonDocument`. Your `Group` call will probably be returning some sort of key and value pair.

Comment: @Ibrennan208 I added the resulting json to the question. It is an array of two integers, according to the default DateTimeOffset serialization routine. But no way of deserializing this array.

Comment: Does `var firstDate = theFirstItem["firstDate"][0].ToUniversalTime();` do anything? Or perhaps `var firstDate = new DateTimeOffset(theFirstItem["firstDate"][0], theFirstItem["firstDate"][1]);`

Comment: @Ibrennan208 The first gives: System.NotSupportedException: 'BsonInt64 does not support ToUniversalTime.'. The second does not compile (no constructor taking those parameters).

Comment: Maybe breaking each of your linq statements apart would help to debug it. `var aggregate = collection.Aggregate();`; `var groupedList = aggregate.Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "Number" }, { "firstDate", new BsonDocument { { "$first", "$Date" } } } });`; `var first = groupedList.First();` That way you can inspect the values and try to retrieve information from each step of your program.

Comment: Sorry, those suggestions were before the question data was updated. But from that you can see that you are able to get the `BsonInt64` from your 2D array you are creating. So perhaps instead of that, you should just be calling `var firstDate = theFirstItem.ToUniversalTime();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that MongoDB serializes the DateTimeOffset as a BsonArray of the ticks (long/Int64) and offset (in minutes). If you do not want to change this, you can deserialize it like this:

```
var array = theFirstItem["firstDate"].AsBsonArray;
var timestamp = array[0].AsInt64;
var offset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(array[1].AsInt32);
var dto = new DateTimeOffset(timestamp, offset);
```

In MQL aggregations, you can use code similar to the following to calculate the time in UTC (unfortunately, .NET uses ticks since 0001-01-01 00:00 whereas MongoDB uses the Unix Epoch als reference point):

```
[{$set: {
  dt: {
    $toDate: {
      $subtract: [
        { $subtract: [
          { $divide: [ { $first: '$Date' }, 10000 ] }, // Convert ticks to ms
          62135596800000 ] // Convert to Unix epoch
        },
        {
          $multiply: [
            { $last: '$Date' }, 60000 ] // respect offset
        }]
      }
    }
}}]
```

If you can change the way how the data is stored and you do not need the offset part, you can adjust the serialization of the value like this:

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
```

Due to the use of the `BsonRepresentation` atribute, MongoDB stores the value as a UTC datetime without the offset. The benefit is that the ISODate in the database can be easily used in MongoDB queries. As all date values are stored in UTC they are easily comparable.

However, if you cannot do without the offset part, another option is to customize the deserialization of the BsonArray-DateTimeOffset, so that the conversion to DateTimeOffset is done during deserialization. See this [link](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.16/reference/bson/serialization/#serializers) for details.